# Remove a DIV using a link

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- content -->
<a href="#" class="remove">remove</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
  return false;
});
```

If there is only one DIV it works OK but when there are multiple DIVS (`class="row"`) it won't do anything. No errors are returned either.

EDIT: I should add that by default there is only one div - additional divs get dynamically created using a jQuery clone function - perhaps this is why it won't recognise the new link/div?

Comment: No, sorry it's not (just removed it).

Comment: Just done some more testing - if there are multiple DIVS then then only the first 'remove' button works - the ones after it don't do anything.

Comment: @GSTAR Could you show us your HTML, please?

Comment: It works for me: [JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FvvmC/).

Comment: I'm with @lonesomeday here, we need to see the whole page. Is your .click hook up inside a $(document).ready construct? May be there's only the first link loaded when your JQuery runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me: [JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FvvmC/).

Given that the other `div`s are dynamically loaded, you need to use:

```
$('.remove').live('click',
  function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
      return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo (featuring add and remove)](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FvvmC/1/).

Comment: You're welcome, but if this answered your question, then an up-vote or accept'd be awesome... =p

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly - it seems to be working as intended - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3AsB/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine for me. Check out my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQWH8/5/) (with added removal animation for fun)

**UPDATE**

each time you create a new items, you need to re-execute the code

```
doCloneObject();

//Once you create the new object(s), tell jQuery what to do with them.
$('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggle('fast', function (){
            $(this).remove();
    });
    return (false);
});
```

Comment: After you perform the clone, you need to re-execute the `$('.remove').click(function(){...});` code to jQuery knows what so do with the new items.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is only run once the whole page has loaded, i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```